# Set scoreboard display to created team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to a create a counter that will be visible only to admins on my 1.15 server.

To do so I create a team `/team add staff "Staff"`

Then create my scoreboard `/scoreboard objectives add counter Counter`. But when I try to show it to team staff by using `/scoreboard setdisplay sidebar.team.staff counter` it tells me `Unknown display slot sidebar.team.staff`

Any help fix it and make my stuffs working would be grateful.
thank

Answer (score 1):

Those slots are for some reason set by colour, not by actual team. I know, the syntax is confusing.

You can assign a colour to a team like this:

```
/team modify staff color blue
```

And then show a scoreboard to all blue teams:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar.team.blue counter
```

This also means that you can have at most 17 sidebars visible to different people at a time, one per colour and one for everyone else (no colour or no team is different from white and you can get it back with `/team modify staff color reset`).